# I lost all the images and container when i switch a new windows account using windows docker desktop

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Is there any one know how to keep the images and containers when i use a new windows account?
my docker container is linux container.

I add this new account to my docker group but start the docker service with my old account, but it's still missing.
I want to keep all the containers in my new account.